# How to call a smart contract function from another smart contract function?

Tags: solidity

Some background first. I have two smart contracts:

- **ERC20** for fungible tokens where I minted my own token/crypto currency;
- **ERC1155** for non-fungible tokens (NFTs);
- The user will buy the NFT minted in the **ERC1155** with the token I minted in the **ERC20** smart contract.

The user calls the function `buyNFT()` in the **ERC1155** that call the function `transfer()` inside the **ERC20** smart contract. My problem relies in making the "bridge" between these two contracts. I've tried using the low-level function `delegatecall()` but with no success since it always returns a tuple whose first value is `false`.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
abstract ERC20 {
    function _transfer(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) internal {}

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

contract ERC1155 {
    function buyNFT(uint256 _NFTPrice, address _to)
        public
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = 0x00...00.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSelector(HRC20.transfer.selector, _to, _NFTPrice)
        );

        if (!success) {
            if (returnData.length == 0) revert("here");

            assembly {
                revert(add(32, returnData), mload(returnData))
            }
        }

        return returnData;
    }

}
```

Sorry for no code highlight, it seems stack overflow doesn't support the `.sol` extension.

Also, I've tried using `abi.encodePacked()`, `abi.encode()`, `abi.encodeWithSignature()`.

Comment: You wish to allow users to buy NFT in exchange for tokens?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I want users to buy NFTs with the token I minted in the ERC20 smart contract.

Comment: Then you don't need to use `transfer` at all. Your users execute `approve`, and your contract executes `transferFrom`.

Comment: And get rid of your `ERC20` implementation. Use OpenZeppelin's.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I've tried using `approve` and then `transferFrom` too. I get the same tuple whose first value is `false`. I can't get rid of the `ERC20` implementation because it is already in production and there is no way to update it. If I haven't expressed myself well, I need to receive payment from the user in the currency I have minted and then transfer ownership of the NFT to that user. Preferably, everything should be done in the same function, so I can roll back the entire transaction if an error occurs.

Comment: In your scheme, `approve` needs to be executed by `EOA`, while `transferFrom` needs to be executed in function `buyNFT`. And you don't need to use delegate calls, or any type of "reflection" (abi.encode stuff). You can call these functions normally.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb you're right. I'll need to work with a different approach than I wanted. Anyway, you've given me some insights, so thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As @bbbbbbbbb had commented, the transaction flow would be:
1 - user calls `approve` function on `ERC20` smart contract, passing the address of `ERC1155` and the NFT price;
2 - user calls the `buyNFT` function on `ERC1155` which will call the `transferFrom` function of `ERC20`;
3 - In this way, the tokens are debited from the user's account and credited to the ERC1155 contract, thus requiring a function to withdraw these payments.

The drawback is that the user needs to sign two transactions to buy the NFT when the used currency to sell it isn't the network token.

The final code would be:

```js
interface ERC20 {
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) internal {}
}

contract ERC1155 {
    ERC20 erc20Contract = ERC20(0x1234...5678);

    function buyNFT(uint256 price)
        external
    {
        erc20Contract.transferFrom(msg.sender, price);
        // I'm assuming the `transferFrom` will revert if user
        // doesn't have sufficient balance, otherwise, we would need to check
        // for the return value and revert if needed

       _mint(msg.sender, tokenId, quantity);
    }

}
```